# WSO API Manager tutorial

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am trying to create and publish a new API, but at the end of the creation of an API I don't have the button "save and publish" I just have "save" so my API is correctly created but not published. Is there anyone who can help me for doing that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which version of API Manager you are using? `Save and Publish` button will be there in Manage Tab.

Comment: You caan change the life cycle phase to published after saving the API

Comment: seems like a valid question. no need to downvote

Answer (score 1):

I think the logged in user does not have relevant permissions to publish the api. See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+User+Roles for relevant user roles for each type of user level and check whether the logged in user has the permissions related to 'publisher' role. If user does not have the publisher permission, he only can create the api.